# How to make a text box that can directly type in Sinhala Unicode?

Tags: web-applications, unicode

I want to make a web page where user can search something using Sinhala Unicode, just typing in a text box, not copy and paste using a [converter like this](http://www.ucsc.cmb.ac.lk/ltrl/services/feconverter/t1.html).

I found [a question in a forum](http://www.htmlforums.com/html-xhtml/t-unicode-textbox-40281.html) about exactly what I want, but I didn't get it well. It tells to use `<input type="text" style="font-family: Sinhalese">`.

Comment: [`<input type="text">` should just work](http://jsfiddle.net/V5hAM/)

Comment: Do you mean that the user should be able to use a Western keyboard and have letters somehow directly converted to Sinhala letters? This would mean that you need to embed a widget like the one on the page you mention, just making it part of your page. If you just mean that users should be able to type in Sinhala letters, then `<input type="text">` surely allows that, as @Esailija says. But users would need to know how to use the software in their computer, such as Input Method Editors, or have a Sinhala keyboard.

Comment: when i type in this comment it is display in english whithout my effort.but if i want to type in sinhala i have to use another conventer.why it is not directly display in sinhala. ex: when i type the word "yunikoerd" it shuld be display in sinhala as "යුනිකෝඩ්". is there any method when i type a english letter in a text box, it automaticaly convert to sinhala

Comment: in other word this link ucsc.cmb.ac.lk/ltrl/services/feconverter/t1.html has two text box that doing my needs.i want to make it in one text box(while typing the english letter it convert to sinhala in same text box)

Answer (score 0):

Try www.EasySinhalaTyping.com. Here you can type in Sinhala Online and also Download and Install Sinhala Typing Software on your PC - So you can type Sinhala even without internet connection.