# jquery trigger key event to textbox from another text box

Tags: jquery, eventtrigger

i want send a key event to simulate `mytext2` from `mytext1` . that means when i type "a" in `mytext1` it should display in `mytext2` also.further when i press backspace on `mytext1` it should be affected in to `mytext2` also. in some case mytext1 has nothing but `mytext2` remaining something,in such a case  when i press backspace on `mytext1` it should be clear last letter in `mytext2` ('it says that i don't want both text box content to be equal').  here is my code:

```
$('#mytext1').on('keydown',function(e){
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

  $('#mytext2').trigger($.Event("keypress", { keyCode: keyCode }));
});

$('#mytext1').on('keypress',function(e){
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  this.val()+=keyCode;
});

 <input type='text' id='mytext1' value='this not eq to txt2'/>
  <input type='text' id='mytext2'value='this not eq to txt1'/>
```

*** even delete, backspace event shuld be trigger to mytext2. just like i'm doing it on mytext2.think that i put same key press on different text box initially with different content

thnks,help me.
------------------update-------------------------------------------------------------------   think initially mytext1 has a value "ca" mytext2 has "bea" ,   when i press "t" on `mytext1` it should be affected in to `mytext2` . then `mytext1` willbe "cat" mytext2 willbe "beat". if i press backspace twice in `mytext1` it will be resulted as `mytext1`=>"c" ,mytext2=>"be". sorry for my poor explaninig.

Comment: `val` is a method of jQuery object, you should code `this.value`.

Comment: thats only my thinking like $('#mytext1').val()=...this refer current object

Comment: Your idea (edited one) seems pretty horrible, you'll see why after playing a bit with any solution. (*Caret position*)

Comment: roXon is right, this is a mess... funny mess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/kNPRM/4/

```
$(function() {

    var a = $('#a');
    var b = $('#b');

    var foo = function(input, string, code) {

        switch(code) {

            case 8:
                var s = input.val();
                input.val(s.substr(0, s.length -1));
                break;

            default:
                var c = String.fromCharCode(code);

                if(c.match(/\w/)) {

                    input.val(input.val() + string.slice(-1));

                }

        }

    };

    a.on('keyup', function(event) {

        foo(b, this.value, event.keyCode);        

    });

    b.on('keyup', function(event) {

        foo(a, this.value, event.keyCode);

    });

});
```

Comment: thanks. you got me.this is my first step to find a solution for my questions on here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739906/how-to-make-a-text-box-that-can-directly-type-in-sinhala-unicode.if i found  a solution.your answer would be help for it.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/urilox/1/edit

```
$('#mytext1').on('input', function() {
  $('#mytext2').val(this.value);
} );
```

If you need to handle a "Paste" event also this is a good way to go. (Modern browsers)

Non-modern use: `keyup paste propertychange`

---

**For an intercommunication between them - do like:**

```
$('#mytext1, #mytext2').on('input', function() {
  $(this).siblings().val(this.value); // put both your inputs strictly inside a neutral parent!
} );
```

**or simply**

```
var $a=$('#mytext1'), $b=$('#mytext2');

$a.on('input', function() {
  $b.val(this.value);
} );
$b.on('input', function() {
  $a.val(this.value);
} );
```

Comment: i want to both text box listening to key event.not just paste in to mytext1 to mytext2.

Comment: @user1822719 I don't understand your comment, I showed you the way to go, than you should do something like: http://jsbin.com/urilox/4/edit ? Hope was not that hard ;)